# What's your look on the verb "revision"?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for a short word that means "to create a new vision" for something.

Maybe the obvious is 'revision', but not sure if that word isn't obsolete... it feels a bit syrupy as a verb.

E.g., revision life or revision society, revision the plan, revision the economy.

What do you think of revision? Any suggestions of other words to cover that meaning?

Alternatively, I have been thinking about: reimagine, recapture, remake, rethink, recreate. But it doesn't cover the meaning that I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help :)

Floris

Comment: I've seen "re-vision" used in this sense.  Gotta have the dash, though, or people will view you as being a revisionary.

Comment: Put another way, the word "revision" relates directly in meaning to the word "revise" and not to the word "vision"; the hyphen in "re-vision" prevents it from being "revision".

Answer (score 2):

To create a new vision for something is to [**reenvision**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reenvision) it:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   variants: or **re-envision**
>
> *transitive verb*
>   : to envision (something) again especially in a different way
>
> // As time wore on, it became easier to *reenvision* a potentially happy future for myself.
>   — Dese'Rae L. Stage
>   // Our library system has *reenvisioned* itself as a technology hub.
>   — Stephanie Rawlings-Blake
>   // The movie is a modern *re-envisioning of a classic* fairy-tale.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is *re-envision*. Definition from lexico:

*View or visualize (something) in a different way with the aim of improving or transforming it*